# React-Select imports fail with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

Trying to get set up with React-Select.
It works fine in a standard React project, but not a Typescript React project (both using Create-React-App with webpack).

In my typescript project, it says "Select" is not exported. I can choose "SelectBase" but that doesn't work as expected.

Steps taken:
I install react-select and @types/react-select via npm.

In my component, when trying to import Select from 'react-select, I get typescript squiggly underline on "Select", with errors (see below).

Configuration used:

```
npm install --save react-select
npm install --save-dev @types/react-select

import Select from 'react-select';  (errors here)
```

Errors:

```
Module '"../../...project.../node_modules/@types/react-select"' has no exported member 'Select'.      ts(2305)


Module '"c:/...project.../node_modules/@types/react-select/index"' has no exported member 'Select'.      ts(2305)
```

The documentation only shows installation using yarn, but I figured npm would be OK too.
Do I need to configure this differently?
Thanks

Comment: Depending on your TypeScript config, you may need to import it using the `* as` construct: `import * as Select from 'react-select';`

Comment: Have you check this issue ? https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3201

Comment: Richard- I tried that. I no longer get an import error, but I'm still not able to use "Select". Using that syntax (the way I understand it), "Select" represents everything within the react-select package, not the actual "Select" module. So within my code I can reference "Select. _____". I can fill in the blank line with specific modules, but the true "Select" module is still not an option. Thanks!

Comment: Laura, thanks. I did see that one. The answer was to not only install the types but to also install the package itself. I have already done both. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have issues when importing  `import { components, ControlProps, Props, Select, StylesConfig, } from "react-select";` it is because Select is the default export of react-select, it can be fixed by doing
`import Select, { components, ControlProps, Props, Select, StylesConfig, } from "react-select";`.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got it working.
I noticed that Typescript was also giving errors with other imports that had been fine the day before. So the issue was not react-select--it was something deeper in my TypeScript configuration that went wrong. I think something got changed when I was troubleshooting something else.
I went back to prior version, installed react-select, then it worked fine. Sorry for the trouble!